# Media Player Flickering in Android ICS

Tags: android, camera, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-mediaplayer

I have an activity. In that there are two surface views. One for camera and other for playing media.

While playing media in the background i am taking pictures. Whenever onpictaken called for the camera, video get jurking.